# Python postional arguments missing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code to be performed on cleaned text. I have written a code. But it is showing various errors.

The code is as follows:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = " "
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    def fun1(self,b):
         self.d1 = dict()
         ch = '@#$%^&*)('
         with open(b,'r') as g:
             g = g.read()
             if any(m in ch for m in g):
                 print("hi")
             else:
                 w = g.split()
             for i in w:
                 if in self.d1:
                     self.d1[i] += 1
                 else:
                     self.d1[i] = 1
         return self.d1
     def fun2(self):
         b = self.fun1()
         w1 = dict()
         c = len(b.d1)
         for w in b.d1:
             w1[w] = b[d1]/c
         return w1

f = a()
f.fun2(b)
```

Throwing an error fun1 missing 1 required positional argument : b

Comment: "fun1" is defined to receive a parameter "b" which isn't given on call.

Answer (score 2):

The function `fun1` requires the parameter `b` and you do not pass it. 
If the parameter `b` is not needed, delete it from the parameters of `fun1`, otherwise pass a value for the parameter `b` when you call `fun1`.

---

It is almost difficult to understand what you wanted to do, but I think you are counting the words and then you are normalizing them for the length of the sentence vocabulary. This is absolutely not the best way to do it. But now at least it works and makes sense:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = " "

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def fun1(self, filepath):
        d1 = {}
        with open(filepath,'r') as g: 
            g = g.read()
            w = g.split()

        #example input for test
        #g = "I love pizza and I love chips" # fake input
        #w = g.split()
            for i in w:
                d1[i] = d1[i] + 1 if i in d1 else 1

        return d1

    def fun2(self):
         d1 = self.fun1(filepath='corpus.txt')
         w1 = {}
         c = len(d1) # Or did you mean by the total number of words? Which you can calculate like this: sum(d1.values()))

         for w in d1:
             w1[w] = d1[w]/c
         return w1

f = a()
f.fun2()
```

and with input examples (commented) gives:

```
# {'I': 0.4, 'love': 0.4, 'pizza': 0.2, 'and': 0.2, 'chips': 0.2}
```

Comment: @klam I updated the answer. If there are any questions, ask. Please vote up my answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: write here in the comments if they are small things and inherent to the same question, for larger questions, it is better that you make a new question and maybe leave the link in the comments.  PS.  accept my answer please.  Thanks

Comment: I updated, now it works, the for-loop must also be inside the 'with' block, I had moved it to do the commented test

Comment: Hi @Massifox, I used it inside with.It didn't work for me. Please read my edited question for more details on fun1().I have edited it.

Comment: you did not properly indent the ‘with’ block code.  Look at my code: g, w, for-loop all have the same indentation level.  in your no.  must be all within the "with" block

Comment: Even after getting everything under with, it is giving the same error @Massifox

Comment: I have now looked at the code you added.  If it is not valid, add ‘return d1’ after printing.  How did you write now does not work because when the string is invalid do not create w, instead when the string is invalid your function must end

Comment: Hi @Massifox, Its giving { } at end. I don't want it how can I remove it?

Comment: it is right that you give {} when your sentence does not respect the conditions you have set.  You can check the return value of fun2 (possibly even fun1).  If you come back {} don't print anything or print an error message